# Why console.log(myObj) prints an error in JS.Bin?

Tags: javascript, object, console.log, destructuring, object-destructuring

Here is a simple exercise that i don't finish to understund:

```
  const myObj = {
       name: 'Max', 
       age: 28
    }

    const {name} = myObj; 
    console.log(name); // prints 'Max'
    console.log(age); // prints undefined
    console.log(myObj); // prints {name: 'Max', age: 28}
```

This is an exercise i found in a course i'm taking. The problem is that when i try the exercise in JSBin it only works console.log(name); the other two prints return this error:

```
"Max"
"error"
"@cotehixumi.js:24:1
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: "_Why console.log(age) prints undefined?_" Because of `const {name} = myObj;` You only asked for the `name` variable from `myObj`.

Comment: You need to destructure all the properties from myObj that you are going to use. You only destructured name and so you're able to successfully log it.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `const {name} = myObj;` You are using the spread operator. What it is basically doing is `const name = myObj["name"]`. The reason `age` is `undefined` is because it isn't taking the `age` from `myObj`.

If you want to fix this, just do `const {name,age} = myObj;`

Comment: That's okay. But... why in JSBin throw an error on the third console.log( ) ?

Comment: I don't know why. I tried it in the chrome console and it didn't throw any errors. Did you have the exact same code in JSBin?

Comment: Okay, it's solved. I had the wrong code. Thanks anyway!